# Is Nagilum immortal/eternal?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In “[Where Silence Has Lease](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Where_Silence_Has_Lease_(episode)),” Nagilum traps the Enterprise with plans to experiment on at least 1/3 of the crew, so that it can study death. Does this imply that Nagilum is immortal (incapable of dying from “old age” or natural causes, but not accident or murder)? Or perhaps its species is simply extremely long-lived, and so none of them had yet died at the point when Nagilum met Picard and company.

Could Nagilum be eternal, existing before the ”Beginning?” This seems unlikely, as only the Q in Star Trek have claimed such a thing about themselves. Though Nagilum very well could be a “brute fact,” without any explanation whatever.

Comment: Or perhaps its memory has a half-life and Nagilum forgot what death was and meant.

Comment: I guess that's possible. But Nagilum seemed so advanced and it just seems unlikely that it'd have a "flaw" in its mind that humans, Klingons, and Bolians do not.

Comment: If you think human memory does not have a half-life I have a bridge to sell you...

Comment: I am not aware of the "half-life" term concerning human memory capacity. Some people have excellent memories. Others, not so much. If this "half-life" concept were true then I shouldn't have any memories of things that occurred years ago. And yet I do.

Comment: I have an excellent long term memory. It provokes comments of astoundment from those who know me. Dates of events from years ago pop into my head. And yet: memory fades. Perhaps your would find the phrase **memory decays** (inexorably) more palatable than **memory has a half-life** (I think you do not understand what "half-life" means: read up on the half-lives of plutonium and cesium-134). Have you never forgoten something?

Comment: Ok, we agree. Memory fades. I guess I just see Nagilum as being "above" losing memories due to its extremely powerful status. I'd also find it surprising if a Douwd, Organian, Metron, Trelane, etc., claimed to forget something. (I know what half-life means, but that's not the exact term you wanted, of course.)

Comment: Every time I learn something new, it pushes one of the old memories out. Remember that time I took the wine-tasting class and forgot how to drive?

Comment: The Prophets had no conception of death before The Sisko, either

Comment: @Lexible, Memory doesn't have a "half life" (there isn't some interval during which you lose half your memories), but that doesn't mean memories don't degrade. Human memory is actually quite unreliable, even within a relatively short time after the event. The mind quickly loses details, but fills in the gaps with the gist of things. You might forget which hitters made single-base plays during a specific game, you might even forget the final score, but you'll probably remember that your team won and that you had a good time.

Comment: @BrianS If there is a quantity of memory, then **yes**, when half those memories are irretrievably forgotten, that is the half-life of that quantity of memories. It may be that different factors (i.e. nature of memory, age of memory, emotional valence of memory, physiological changes, etc.) *alter* the rate of decay (i.e. I am not suggesting there is a constant rate of decay), but there most certainly is a half life.

Comment: @Lexible, no you're not describing constant rate of decay. By using the term "half life", you are describing **exponential** rate of decay.

Comment: You have the eastern Europe concept of "the ultimate reality," have you not? Does that imply a level of Reality upon which other "reality" is based? If so, does this imply that It need not be subject to such limiting universal functions as time? If so, could this further imply that the concepts of "beginning" and "end" need not apply to It? If so, what is the 'It" behind that "Reality" that enables this to be so? India calls It "Brahma," implying a Being supreme above all others. Beings--at least intelligent ones--tend to possess wills. If such a Being exists, whatever Its name, how do we know

Answer (score 4):

The very clear implication is that Nagilum is immortal, in the fullest sense of the word. He is eternally living. Our best evidence is that, for want of a better explanation he seems to lack any experience of, or even the concept of death.

> Is it also true that you have only a limited existence?...You exist --
>   and then you cease to exist? **Your minds call it "death."**

---

Nagilum himself (itself?) seems to exist in a pocket universe of his own devising. Data describes it as a...

> Lack of dimension

rather than an *alternate* dimension (like fluidic space) or a subspace realm like we see in Schisms.

Given his obvious level of control over this region of non-space, and the fact that such a place (or non-place, to be precise) would survive the end of our universe, there's no special reason to assume that he would be subject to the same mortality as other more mundane energy life-forms.

Comment: When you say, "in the fullest sense of the word," do you not think that Q or perhaps a Douwd could dispatch of Nagilum? Also, I figured that Nagilum's void was part of the universe as a whole, and thus would not be immune to the effects of the end of the universe.

Comment: @T-1000 - Data describes it as being 'not a dimension', rather than a separate dimension. That would seem to indicate that it's not bound to our own 11-dimensional universe. As to the question of which god would win in a fist-fight, my money would be on Nagilum.

Comment: Interesting. I thought everyone considered Q the top dog in Star Trek.

Comment: @T-1000, alas they seem alarmingly mortal after the events of "The Q and the Grey".

Comment: Only because Q-weapons were being used. I bet Q-weapons would damage Nagilum also!

Comment: There's no real evidence of the comparative strength of Qs and Nagilum, unlike between Qs and say, Douwd. So the most we can say is; "they both be powerful, y'all."

Answer (score 1):

If the concept of existing since the dawn of time bothers you, then how about this: Nagilum's species evolved over time and its life expectancy continued to increase until its life expectancy got so long that it became longer than the life of the universe, or at least so long that Nagilum could not remember anyone around him ever dying. Perhaps this is an example of extreme [punctuated equilibrium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punctuated_equilibrium) - Nagilum's race was fairly normal until at one point a rapid change led to them becoming immortal or close to it.

Basically what I'm trying to say is that immortality doesn't necessarily imply being eternal.

Comment: I don't have a problem with immortal beings in the Star Trek universe. The Douwd claims immortality and I fully believe that this is true---to a point. I think that the Douwd, like Nagilum, is immortal from aging. Kevin Uxbridge could sit in a chair for eternity (provided the universe didn't end), and he'd never cease to exist from natural causes. However, I do think that Nagilum and the Douwd can die from accident or murder. "Eternal" is a different matter: it suggests that a being has no explanation, but is rather like a "brute fact." I think only the Q would fall into this category.